# placing text over image in navbar bootstrap 4 dreamweaver

Tags: image, text, bootstrap-4, navbar, dreamweaver

i am trying to build a responsive website using bootstrap and dreamweaver.
I would like to place an image in my navbar, and place a text link over the image. Im having some trouble getting the text to sit over the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the source code:

```
    </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="files /button images/swirl 1 11.svg" alt="" width="130"  class="d-inline-block align-top">
    Tom
  </a>
</nav>
```

Here is my own css sheet i linked to override bootstarps:

```
   body{
    background-color:#F00;

}
nav a{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you need to add a bit of custom css like so:

```html
.navbar-brand {
    background: url("https://placeimg.com/130/40/animals") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 130px;
}
```

Replace that with your SVG and you should be good to go.

That creates a background image for the element with the `navbar-brand` class.

Comment: Also, to ensure the minimum width of 130px, you should add the following to that custom css: `min-width: 130px;`